# Statute of limitations tolling while a California debtor is not in the state after defaulting

Tags: debt, statute-of-limitations

In layman's terms, how exactly does [Section 351 of the CCP](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?sectionNum=351.&lawCode=CCP) apply to a person who defaulted on a private unsecured loan or credit card, thinking on a timeline? The creditor does have the valid phone number, email and mailing address (not in CA) of the debtor.

Something like this?

1. Debtor obtains a loan while they are in California
2. Debtor leaves the state but continues to make payments
3. Debtor defaults
4. [4.1](https://www.debt.org/faqs/americans-in-debt/consumer-california/) years later, the creditor attempts to serve the debtor
5. Debtor is not found at their last known CA address
6. The statute tolls, so the plaintiff can still sue? For how long does it toll? How is it determined for how long the debtor was not in the state?

Can other statute provisions apply, such as those in the state of the creditor or forum selected by them, or those in the state of the mailing address of the debtor?

Comment: "How is it determined for how long the debtor was not in the state?" Statute of limitations is an affirmative defense. It is raised by the debtor and proven in the course of the lawsuit with evidence, like all other issues.